# log CPU register changes in ARM Linux

Tags: linux, arm, cpu-registers

I would like to know how to monitor multiple registers changes for a application in ARM linux. I know I have to debug it, but how I can automatically log all register changes in ARM linux?

I know that with watch command in gdb I can do that, but is it possible to make a small c code which only run an application like a debugger, and record its register changes?

Simply put, I would like to monitor CPU registers changes in ARM linux. So if I run a application, I'd like to monitor all of its register changes.

Let's say I want to monitor R14. I would like to log all of the changes and the values in the R14 register, when the application is running.

Comment: Could you possibly expand upon what you're asking? Also, try to limit how many questions you're asking.

Comment: It should _in theory_ be possible to write a debugger (or script a suitably powerful existing one) to scan a binary, breakpoint every instruction targeting a particular register, and handle each breakpoint by logging the value (slightly trickier with loads). Provided of course you don't have any concurrency/timing issues to worry about. Really, this is exactly the sort of thing that hardware trace units are for.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go would be using gdb to single-step into your program, recording the output of `info all-registers` between each step. Automating this should not be a big problem IMO.

However, your programs running time would be *much* longer.

Answer (score 1):

In GDB you can print the values of cpu registers,

`info registers` 
shows all the registers;

`info registers <reg_name>`

shows just the register `<reg_name>`.

Also,

```
info all-registers
```

with which you can get the register name you are interested in -- very useful for finding platform specific registers (like on ARM)

P.S.
If you're looking for assembly code to read cpu reg. then this thread might help you http://www.keil.com/forum/19829/

Comment: Well this is only doing for one step. I wanted to record entire register changes in all instructions within application. the better way is to use "watch $register-name" in gdb. but thats not what I am looking. I need something lighter, and I need to record it in a file.